# URLForResource working in Debug but not Release?

Tags: nsbundle

Running into a strange issue which has me dumbfounded. I use URLForResource, calling it on the main bundle to get a file that is bundled in the app. It's just the standard :

NSURL* fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@"myfile" withExtension:@"myext"];

that I've used a million times...

The issue is - in this app, it works in Debug, but if I build Release it returns nil ?! This is bizarre, the file is there, I can see it in the package and all, I have no idea why it behaves this way. It is also true for any file in the bundle not a specific one.

Does anyone have an idea what is going on or has encountered such strange behavior before? I'm on Xcode 4.3.2 btw..

Thanks

Comment: maybe this is the answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298593/html-resource-being-loaded-correctly-in-debug-mode-and-not-in-release-mode